# Passing Attributes to Append function in Jquery Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass attributes to a jquery append function. It appends the html but does not append the attributes. There are no errors shown in the console either. 
Html Code :

```
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
```

Javascript Code :

```
    $('li').each(function(){
        $(this).append('<span></span>', {
            text: 'some text',
            class: 'someClass'
        })
    });
```

I want the HTML to look like

```
 <li>First Item <span class="someClass">some text</span></li>
 <li>Second Item Item <span class="someClass">some text</span></li>
```

Comment: Why did you expect it to work at all? The documentation does not mention anything in this regard: http://api.jquery.com/append/.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) is a Method which accepts string arguments or a function
`.append("<p>A</p>", "<p>B</p>")` or `.append(function() {});` - so you're passing an invalid Object as argument.

**Instead**, use `$("<HTMLTag>", {...options})` to [**Create New Elements**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#creating-new-elements)

```js
$("li").each(function(){

  $("<span>", {
    class: "someClass", 
    text: " some text",
    appendTo: this,
  });
  
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had seen a tutorial by netttus in which he used to append the way i did. Can you please elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('li').each(function(){
        $('<span/>',{
            text: 'some text',
            class: 'someClass'
        }).appendTo(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$(this).append('<span class="someClass">some text</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for append is (and I quote jQuery documentation) :

> One or more additional DOM elements, arrays of elements, HTML strings, or jQuery objects to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements.